# Rename every 2 column with same from another data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 sample data frames:

```
df1 = 

a_1  b_1  a_2  b_2
  1    2    3    4
  5    6    7    8
```

and

```
df2 = 

 c    
12
14
```

---

I want to add values of `c` as a suffix in order:

```
df3 = 

12_a_1  12_b_1  14_a_2  14_b_2
     1       2       3       4
     5       6       7       8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is list comprehension:

```
import itertools
# use itertools to repeat values of df2
prefix = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(str(x), 2) for x in df2['c'].values))

# list comprehension to create new column names
df1.columns = [p+'_'+c for c,p in zip(df1.columns, prefix)]
print(df1)

   12_a_1  12_b_1  14_a_2  14_b_2
0       1       2       3       4
1       5       6       7       8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` and `map`

```
s = (df1.columns.str.split('_').str[-1].astype(int) - 1).map(df2.c)
df1.columns = s.astype(str) + '_' + df1.columns
print(df1)

Out[304]:
   12_a_1  12_b_1  14_a_2  14_b_2
0       1       2       3       4
1       5       6       7       8
```